# How to use specific index in Map function es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I have map function and i know the index also instead of iterating all the values i need only one particular value in that map how do i do that ?

```
 Result.map(function(product,index) { 
             
            product.data.map(function(attribute){
                    
                    if (attribute.id == fieldName) 
                    {
                      console.log('details',detail);
                      
                      attribute.Qty= 1;
                    
              
            });
        });
```

i have tried something like this

```
  const list1 = Result.map(e => e.data[currIndex].Qty)[rowIndex];
```

and my mock data is

```
0: {data: Array(6)}
1: {data: Array(10)}
2: {data: Array(7)}


data: Array(6)
0:
{
 id: 001
 Qty: 1
},
{
 id: 002
 Qty: 2
},
{
 id: 003
 Qty: 3
},
{
 id: 004
 Qty: 4
},
{
 id: 005
 Qty: 5
},
{
 id: 006
 Qty: 6
}
```

and i need to get something like matching id : 005 need to update the Qty to 5

```
0: {data: [id: 005,Qty: 5]}
```

Comment: The output you're looking for is an invalid data structure. Maybe `{ data: { id: 5, Qty: 5 } }`? What are you doing about the other other arrays. Do you have to find the same match in them too?

Answer (score 0):

I got an invalid data structure error and an octal prefix error when I reproduced your use case. I fixed it up a bit to illustrate how you can match your `id` and change the value of `Qty` You can do this quite simply using `map`.

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Parameters**

`callbackFn` - Function that is called for every element of arr. Each time callbackFn executes, the returned value is added to newArray.

The `callbackFn` function accepts the following arguments:

`element` - The current element being processed in the array.

`indexOptional` - The index of the current element being processed in the array.

`arrayOptional` - The array map was called upon.

`thisArgOptional` - Value to use as this when executing callbackFn.

**Example**

```
let data = [
    {id: 0o01, Qty: 1},
    {id: 0o02, Qty: 2},
    {id: 0o03, Qty: 3},
    {id: 0o04, Qty: 4},
    {id: 0o05, Qty: 5}
];

const editData = (myData, id, newValue) =>
    myData.map((obj, index) => {
        console.log('index value: ', index)
        if (obj.id === id) obj.Qty = newValue
    })

editData(data, 0o05, 555)
console.log(data)
```

**Output**

```
index value:  0
index value:  1
index value:  2
index value:  3
index value:  4
[
  { id: 1, Qty: 1 },
  { id: 2, Qty: 2 },
  { id: 3, Qty: 3 },
  { id: 4, Qty: 4 },
  { id: 5, Qty: 555 }
]
```

Comment: how do i get index?

Comment: Hey! you can get access to the index by passing it to the .map() method. I've updated the answer to illustrate an example.